# How to set cron in linux server?

Tags: php, linux, email, cron

Hi i have created a birthday notification. My Cron URL is http://dev.raddyx.in/bday/birthday.php

I want to set cron run in every 24 hour but i am unable to run in the Linux server.

Check my command:-

```
50  10  *   *   *   curl -s -o /dev/null http://dev.raddyx.in/bday/birthday.php
```

Please help me how to set cron in Linux server?

Comment: Where did you enter this? Did you edit your crontab file? What happens or doesn't happen, are you getting any errors?

Comment: i don't know where is showing error. i am not sure crontab is running or not

Comment: how did you set this one? Through cpanel or through terminal? If you terminal access. type crontab -e in that terminal and see what is in there

Comment: @Chinmay at what time you want cron to be run? at midnight every day ?

Comment: @Sabari its 10:50 AM in everyday

Comment: I suggest to write a shell script e.g. `birthday.sh` which uses `logger` (to log messages) and then do the `curl` command, and run that `birthday.sh` script from your `crontab` entry.

Comment: What command will be in birthday.sh? Please suggest me i am totally unknown in linux.

Answer (score 1):

Are you entering this in `/etc/crontab`? If so, then you will also need to specify the user that the command is to run as, in the sixth field:

```
50  10  *   *   *  root curl -s -o /dev/null http://dev.raddyx.in/bday/birthday.php
```

You may want to look in `/var/log/cron` for some leads on the problem.

Comment: I am unable to find `/var/log/cron`

Comment: @Chinmay Which Linux distribution are you running?

Comment: I don't know which distribution. Can you say me ho to know the distribution?

Comment: I usually find out with either `cat /proc/version` or `uname -a`. Also, if you're concerned about whether the cron daemon is running or not (I would be surprised if it isn't), then check if `ps aux | grep [c]rond` returns info on the process.

Answer (score 0):

Check the CURL is available or not otherwise you can use wget to execute the request

This will execute every 10:50. You can try this also

```
50 10 * * * /usr/bin/wget -O- http://dev.raddyx.in/bday/birthday.php >> /dev/null
```

This will dump your errors into this cronerror.txt file

```
59 10 * * *  /usr/bin/wget -q /var/www/<your log folder path>/cronerror.txt http://dev.raddyx.in/bday/birthday.php
```

Comment: This working for me in past two years. May be your wget installation path is in different place for more refernce http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_wget.htm

Comment: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_wget.htm use only wget instead of /usr/bin/wget use like 50 10 * * * wget error_path httppath

Comment: how to know wget installation path?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42833/discussion-between-chinmay-and-sundar)